# How to resolve the Unable save the extension attributes

Tags: magento2, checkout, knockoutjs, magento2.3.1

I followed this link for creating the custom address field.

I'm getting this error

**PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderExtension::setCustomerAddrId()**

http://techjeffyu.com/blog/magento-2-add-a-custom-field-to-checkout-shipping

how to resolve this. Please help me.

/var/www/html/horseware_down/app/code/Dev/Testing/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement">
        <plugin name="save_custom_notes_in_quote" type="Dev\Testing\Plugin\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

events.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="extra_shipping_cost" instance="Dev\Testing\Observer\SaveOrderObserver" />
    </event>
    <event name="sales_model_service_quote_submit_before">
        <observer name="dev_sales_model_service_quote_submit_before" instance="Dev\Testing\Observer\SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

extension_attributes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
    <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="customer_addr_id" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor">
        <plugin name="add_custom_notes_checkout_form" type="Dev\Testing\Plugin\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Observer/SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore.php

```
<?php
namespace Dev\Testing\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class SalesModelServiceQuoteSubmitBefore implements ObserverInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Observer $observer
     * @return $this
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order */
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getData('order');

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getData('quote');
        $shippingAddressData = $quote->getShippingAddress()->getData();
        if (isset($shippingAddressData['customer_addr_id'])) {
            $order->getShippingAddress()->setCustomerAddrId($shippingAddressData['customer_addr_id']);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

SaveOrderObserver.php

```
<?php
namespace Dev\Testing\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        $order->setData('customer_addr_id', $quote->getCustomerAddrId());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

app/code/Dev/Testing/Plugin/Checkout/Block/Checkout/LayoutProcessor.php

```
<?php
namespace Dev\Testing\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer as EventObserver;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class SaveOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
        $quote = $observer->getEvent()->getQuote();

        $order->setData('customer_addr_id', $quote->getCustomerAddrId());

        return $this;
    }
}
```

app/code/Dev/Testing/Plugin/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php

```
<?php
namespace Dev\Testing\Plugin\Checkout\Model;


class ShippingInformationManagement
{
    protected $quoteRepository;

    protected $dataHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteRepository $quoteRepository
    )
    {
        $this->quoteRepository = $quoteRepository;
    }

    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
    )
    {
        if(!$extensionAttributes = $addressInformation->getExtensionAttributes())
        {
            return;
        }
        
        $quote = $this->quoteRepository->getActive($cartId);
        $quote->setCustomerAddrId($extensionAttributes->getCustomerAddrId());
    }
}
```

Dev\Testing\Setup\InstallSchema.php

```
<?php
namespace Dev\Testing\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallSchemaInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\SchemaSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

class InstallSchema implements InstallSchemaInterface
{
    public function install(
        SchemaSetupInterface $setup, 
        ModuleContextInterface $context
    ){
        $setup->startSetup();

        $quote = $setup->getTable('quote');
        $salesOrder = $setup->getTable('sales_order');
        
        
        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $quote,
            'customer_addr_id',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' =>'Customer Addr Id'
            ]
        );
        
        $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
            $salesOrder,
            'customer_addr_id',
            [
                'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                'nullable' => true,
                'comment' =>'Customer Addr Id'
            ]
        );
        
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```

app/code/Dev/Testing/view/frontend/web/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default.js

```
define(
    [
        'jquery',
        'ko',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager',
        'mage/storage',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address'
    ],
    function (
        $,
        ko,
        quote,
        resourceUrlManager,
        storage,
        paymentService,
        methodConverter,
        errorProcessor,
        fullScreenLoader,
        selectBillingAddressAction
    ) {
        'use strict';

        return {
            saveShippingInformation: function () {
                var payload;

                if (!quote.billingAddress()) {
                    selectBillingAddressAction(quote.shippingAddress());
                }
                
                var customer_addr_id = $('[name="custom_attributes[customer_addr_id]"]').val();

                payload = {
                    addressInformation: {
                        shipping_address: quote.shippingAddress(),
                        billing_address: quote.billingAddress(),
                        shipping_method_code: quote.shippingMethod().method_code,
                        shipping_carrier_code: quote.shippingMethod().carrier_code,
                        extension_attributes:{
                            customer_addr_id: customer_addr_id  
                    
                        }
                    }
                };

                fullScreenLoader.startLoader();

                return storage.post(
                    resourceUrlManager.getUrlForSetShippingInformation(quote),
                    JSON.stringify(payload)
                ).done(
                    function (response) {
                        quote.setTotals(response.totals);
                        paymentService.setPaymentMethods(methodConverter(response.payment_methods));
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                ).fail(
                    function (response) {
                        errorProcessor.process(response);
                        fullScreenLoader.stopLoader();
                    }
                );
            }
        };
    }
);
```

app/code/Dev/Testing/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    "map": {
        "*": {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default': 'Dev_Testing/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default'
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to change **extension_attributes.xml** :-

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Api/etc/extension_attributes.xsd">
      <extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
           <attribute code="customer_addr_id" type="string" />
      </extension_attributes>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to review your Javascript/HTML Templates to debug why `getCustomAttributeLabel` is not a function.

Without seeing your code it's difficult to tell you why.

It could be you are trying to access the value as a KO observable when it isn't created as one?

Comment: I followed the same thing as given in this link

http://techjeffyu.com/blog/magento-2-add-a-custom-field-to-checkout-shipping

Comment: That article doesn't contain `getCustomAttributeLabel` so it sounds like you have removed or overridden something Magento needs. Without seeing all your code it isn't easy to say what.

Comment: added the code. please check. please are not passing into quote and order tables @Ben Crook

Answer (score 0):

you can take a reference from this extension

https://github.com/sivajik34/Custom-Fee-Magento2/tree/master/Sivajik34/CustomFee

Comment: I need for shipping attribute

Comment: yes its using same code. please look it once

Answer (score 0):

The issue is extension_attribute.xml file

```
 <extension_attributes for="Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface">
        <attribute code="customer_addr_id" type="string" />
    </extension_attributes>
```

above code should turn into

```
<extension_attributes for="Magento\Quote\Api\Data\AddressInterface">
            <attribute code="customer_addr_id" type="string"/>
        </extension_attributes>
```

https://codeblog.experius.nl/magento-2-add-extra-billing-or-shipping-field-to-the-checkout/

Better Explanation in their.
But there also made a mistake in extension_attribute.xml.